# how to get the variable for every submit

Tags: php, forms

How can I get the variable `$mygrade['class'];` for every submit?

Here is my code:

```
<?php foreach($mysubject as $row): ?>
    <?php $mygrade = $grade->getgrade($row['id']); ?>    
    <?php $teacher = $grade->getteacher($row['id']); ?>                           
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['subject']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $mygrade['class']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $mygrade['Ts']; ?></td>

        <td><?php echo $mygrade['Dw']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $mygrade['Ex']; ?></td> 
       <td><?php echo $mygrade['Av']; ?></td> 
       <td><?php echo $teacher  ?></td>

        <td>  <form  action="index.php" method="post"> <select name="typere">
           <div class="form-group">     
            <div class="col-md-4">                                         
            <option value="Ts">Ts</option>
            <option value="Dw">Dw</option>
            <option value="Ex">Ex</option>
            <option value="Av">Av</option>
            </select>
               <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="recour" name="submit"/>


            </div></div>
            </form>
       </td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well your first problem is that none of your PHP calls are within the form. So you need to move them in there.

For example try the following:

```
<form  action="index.php" method="post"> 
  <input type="text" name="class" value="<?php $mygrade['class']; ?>"></input>
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="recour" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

When the page is rendered the php code will fire for the first ( and only ) time, as the server produces the document. Once this happens the PHP code embedded in the html code will be populate.

Remember that PHP runs on the server, not the client (browser).

When the form is submitted you can reference the class by the input name, here it is class.

You can do a lot with php and have it render as HTML. Another quick example:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <?php 
      $htmlcode = "<h1>This is from PHP!</h1>";
      echo $htmlcode;
    ?>

    <html>
        <?php 
          $htmlcode = "<head></head><body>This is my body</body></head>";
          echo $htmlcode;
        ?>
    </html>
```

Comment: `</input>` isn't a valid closing tag btw

Comment: @Fred-ii- No it isn't, thanks for the catch. Been awhile.

Comment: hello @jack  firstly thanyou for answer  i use another way  i use my php  after the form direcly but  now all the table table the same value

Comment: I gave you an example of how to do it. You should be able to fill in the blanks with a little analysis.